# How to display the role name in the dialog box when Delete button is pressed

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I've a table specifying the roles and actions, if I check in the role and press delete button, then I should get a dialog box indicating that specific role

If I click on add button, I should get a dialog box or message box with the list of few other roles and on clicking on that role, a rolename should be displayed that has to be added to the respective table

I've created the sap.m.Table and I'm binding the JSON data

Enclosed the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f3u6.png) of the UI:

[image]

I've tried with various methods and I'm enclosing my code

Here is the code..

I can delete the item from the table, but I should get a dialog/message box indicating that, the checkmarked role in the table has been deleted

```
    <script>
    function delete1()
    {
        var v = false;
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            v = true;
            alert("Checked item in the table will be deleted from the table");
      });

      if (v == false)
      {
        alert("Please check the item to be deleted");
      }
      $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').closest("tr").remove();
    }
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("JSon/etc5.json");
        // Load JSON in model
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"model1");
        //create table                          
        //"cells"  
        var oRoles = new sap.m.Text({text: "{model1>Role}"});   
        var oAction = new sap.m.Button({text: "DETAILS", 
                                         type : sap.m.ButtonType.Emphasized,
                                        
                        });
                         // corresponding columns  
                         
                        var oColAbbr = new sap.m.Column({header: new sap.m.Text({text:"ROLES"}) });  
                        var oColAct = new sap.m.Column({header: new sap.m.Text({text:"ACTION"}) }); 
                        // row template  
                        var oRow = new sap.m.ColumnListItem();  
                        oRow.addCell(oRoles).addCell(oAction);  
                        
                     // instantiating the table  
                        var oTab = new sap.m.Table("app",{
                            inset : true,
                            headerText : "SOME DATA",
                            headerDesign : sap.m.ListHeaderDesign.Standard,         
                            includeItemInSelection : false,
                        });  
                        oTab.addColumn(oColAbbr).addColumn(oColAct);  
                        oTab.bindItems("model1>/emp", oRow); //binding data to the tables
                        oTab.setMode(sap.m.ListMode.MultiSelect);
                        
                        var oButton = new sap.m.Toolbar({
                    content: [
                              new sap.m.ToolbarSpacer(),
                              new sap.m.Button({
                                text : "ADD",
                                textAlign : "Center",
                                width : "10%",
                                type: sap.m.ButtonType.Emphasized,
                                press: function() {
                        //              oCDialog2.open();
                                        },
                            }),
                            new sap.m.Label({text:""}),
                            new sap.m.Button({
                                    text : "DELETE",
                                    textAlign : "Center",
                                    width : "10%",
                                    type: sap.m.ButtonType.Reject,
                                    press: function() {
                            //          oCDialog1.open(); 
                                         delete1();
                                    }
                            }),
                        ]
                    });
                    //creating the icons
                     var iTab = new sap.m.IconTabBar({
                         
                         items:[
                                
                                 new sap.m.IconTabFilter({
                                    text: "HR",
                                    icon: "sap-icon://group",
                                    content:[oTab]         
                                 }),                                     
                            ]
                      });           
                    var page = sap.m.Page({
        content: [iTab,oButton],
        showHeader : false,
        enableScrolling : true,
    });
    var app = sap.m.App();
    app.addPage(page);
    app.placeAt("content");
</script>
```

Comment: Please share some code so it will be easier for others to help you :)

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Oh no! Try not to do it by grabbing stuff from the DOM. Use the proper UI5 APIs instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easiest to use the Checkbox control and bind it's value to the same model as where the item lines come from (model1>/emp). In your delete method, you could then easily iterate through the `emp` array and test on the value representing the checkbox.

Whenever you delete an entry from the array, either UI5's MessageToast or MessageBox controls to show the message. Alerts may be blocked by "Check here to disable alerts from this website" functionality in some browsers.

You may also want to change the `$.each` to a `$.grep` instead. This loops through an array in pretty much the same way as `$.each` with one exception. If you return true from the callback, the element is retained. Otherwise, it is removed from the array.

Your code should look something like this:

```
items = this.getView().getModel("model1").getProperty("/emp");
items = $.grep(items, function (el, i) {
    if (el.propertyBoundToCheckbox) { 
        MessageToast.show("Deleting entry: " + el.getName())
        return false;
    }
    return true; // keep the element in the array
});
```

Note: The code above pulls the model from the view, as that's a best practice. Try not to tie anything to the core, as the core is shared between all applications running in the browser window (e.g. in Fiori Launch Pad scenario).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and guidelines jpenninkhof sir, I'm new to the sapui5 development, suggest me some links where I can learn clearly about sapui5, as of now I'm refering the walkthrough tutorials and following few of the SCN blogs...If you have any other links, please provide the link which will be helpful for the freshers like me

Comment: I personally think the UI5 course on open.sap.com is really great. It's free and still open for self paced learning. I would really recommend this course if you're interested in picking up UI5. Oh, and did I mention it's totally free? ;)